# ObjectMapper - Read/ Write a Generic Object

Tags: java, fasterxml

I have a scenario where I am pushing Object to Queue which will be read on other end.

I am converting my Object to String, String to bytes. Pushing these bytes on to the queue.

```
        CollectionObject collectionObject = new CollectionObject();
        // This can be any Object. Or at least Iam thinking it's Object class.
        collectionObject.setName("Sienna");

        String customerMessage = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(collectionObject);
        byte[] msg = customerMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

On the other end, I am taking reading this object this way.

```
        String messageFromQueue = new String(msg);
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        Object genericObject = objectMapper.readValue(messageFromQueue, new TypeReference<Object>(){});

        System.out.println("let's see object"+genericObject);
        if(genericObject instanceof CollectionObject)
            System.out.println("turned out to be collectionObject "+genericObject);
```

But the instance of check is never satisfied. The readValue returns me LinkedHashMap object.

Any help,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `List<CollectionObject> xyz = mapper.convertValue(messageFromQueue, new TypeReference<List<CollectionObject>>() { });` ?

Comment: That works definitely. But I have to convert to Object class and check instance of

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

There is nothing indicating the class to marshal to: `{"name":"Sienna"}`. How could fasterxml possibly guess which type it should marshal to.

**One solution**

First enable default typing:

```
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

Then consider using a wrapper object around the actual payload:

```
public class Wrapper {

    private Object content;

    public Wrapper() {
    }

    public Wrapper(Object content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Object getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Object content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Then to write the object:

```
    String customerMessage = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Wrapper(collectionObject));
```

Then to read the object:

```
    Object genericObject = objectMapper.readValue(messageFromQueue, Wrapper.class).getContent();
```

In this case `genericObject` will be a `CollectionObject`, and the json is `{"content":["CollectionObject",{"name":"Sienna"}]}`